# How to target current section to close, leaving all others open, using slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple `section` divs on a paage. I am using a simple approach to open and close the sections. I using `slideToggle()` and it is working great, but right now I am having problem trying to locate only the section user has clicked on to close - and not all section at once.

```js
$(".section_accordian_trigger").click(function(){
            //open container and not all containers at once
            $(this).find(".section_container").slideToggle("slow", function(){});
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
        <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
        <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
        </div>
    <section>
    <section>
    <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
        <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
        </div>
    <section>
    <section>
    <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
        <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
        </div>
    <section>
    <section>
    <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
        <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
        </div>
    <section>
```

So the structure is we have a `section`, inside that we have a div that triggers the click event, and then we have a div called `section_container` that hold the content we wish to show and hide. I've been playing around with targeting the `$(this)` (which is the `.section_accordian_target` element clicked), finding the `section_container` class and then calling on `slideToggle`, but this seems to still close all elements at once. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$(this).next(".section_container")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.next()` to target immediately following sibling. `.find()` targets descendant elements

```
$(this).next(".section_container").slideToggle();
```

```js
$(".section_accordian_trigger").click(function() {
  //open container and not all containers at once
  $(this).next(".section_container").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

```css
.section_container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
  <div class="section_container">
    content of section is here
  </div>
  <section>
    <section>
      <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
      <div class="section_container">
        content of section is here
      </div>
      <section>
        <section>
          <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
          <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
          </div>
          <section>
            <section>
              <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
              <div class="section_container">
                content of section is here
              </div>
              <section>
```

Comment: what if i have the the html markup like this `<section><div class="whatever"><div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div><div class="content">content here</div></div></section>` where i have the click trigger div inside a div itself?

Comment: @HollerTrain Where is `section_container` then? Please elaborate

Comment: sorry my markup was wrong. here it would be: `<section><div class="whatever"><div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div><div class="section_container">content here</div></div></section>`- so only thing different from my OP is we now have a div wrapping around the div that does the triggering

Comment: Still `$(this).next(".section_container")` will work

Comment: does not for me using `$(this).next(".section_container").slideToggle("slow", function(){});`

Comment: the structure would be

- section
-- .whatever
--- .section_accordian_trigger
-- //end whatever
--- //end section_accordian_trigger
- section_container
-//end section_container
- //end section

Comment: Seems `$(this).closest('.whatever ').next(".section_container")`

Comment: awesome you rock. i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `.next()` since `.section_container` is not a child of `.section_accordian_trigger`

**Demo**

```js
$(".section_accordian_trigger").click(function() {
  //open container and not all containers at once
  $(this).next(".section_container").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

```css
.section_container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
  <div class="section_container">
    content of section is here
  </div>
  <section>
    <section>
      <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
      <div class="section_container">
        content of section is here
      </div>
      <section>
        <section>
          <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
          <div class="section_container">
            content of section is here
          </div>
          <section>
            <section>
              <div class="section_accordian_trigger">click</div>
              <div class="section_container">
                content of section is here
              </div>
              <section>
```